# How to tranform a SQL query to a KnexJS function with a joining function

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I'm trying to convert the following query in PSQL to KnexJS

```
SELECT
    sum("current")
FROM (
    SELECT
        "study_id",
        "site_id",
        "status",
        max("day") AS "day"
    FROM
        "candidates"
    WHERE
        "study_id" in('TBX1')
        AND "status" in('INCOMPLETE')
    GROUP BY
        "study_id",
        "site_id",
        "status") AS "latest"
    INNER JOIN "candidates" ON "latest"."day" = "candidates"."day"
        AND "latest"."study_id" = "candidates"."study_id"
        AND ("latest"."site_id" = "candidates"."site_id" or 
            ("latest"."site_id" is null and "candidates"."site_id" is null))
        AND "latest"."status" = "candidates"."status";
```

I was able to get until this point but I'm missing the part of the query where I compare with NULL and I don't know how to add that to my Knex function

```
const group = [columns.studyId, columns.siteId, columns.status];
    const filterFn = this.filter;
    const x = this.tx
      .sum(selectColumn)
      .from(function subQuery() {
        this.select(group).max(columns.day, { as: 'day' }).from(tableName).groupBy(group).as('latest');
        filterFn.call({ builder: this }, filter);
      })
      .join(tableName, function joinOn() {
        [columns.day, ...group].map(column =>
          this.on(`latest.${column}`, `${tableName}.${column}`).on(
            this.tx.raw(`("latest"."site_id" = "candidates"."site_id" or
           ("latest"."site_id" is null and "candidates"."site_id" is null))`)
          )
        );
      })
```

The join method is creating my joins but without the NULL comparison I miss this part from the original query

```
 AND ("latest"."site_id" = "candidates"."site_id" or 
     ("latest"."site_id" is null and "candidates"."site_id" is null))
```

Cannot understand how to add that last part to complete my query function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky bit looks to be because you only want the `null` part of the join for the `site_id` column but currently it is included inside the `map` function call so will apply each time through the loop. One way to handle it would be to add an `if` statement for the special case needed for `site_id`. i.e.

```js
const group = [columns.studyId, columns.siteId, columns.status];
    const filterFn = this.filter;
    const x = this.tx
      .sum(selectColumn)
      .from(function subQuery() {
        this.select(group).max(columns.day, { as: 'day' }).from(tableName).groupBy(group).as('latest');
        filterFn.call({ builder: this }, filter);
      })
      .join(tableName, function () {
        [columns.day, ...group].map(column => {
            if (column === 'site_id') {
                this.on(function () {
                    this.on(`latest.${column}`, `${tableName}.${column}`)
                        .orOn(function () {
                            this.onNull(`latest.${column}`)
                                .onNull(`${tableName}.${column}`);
                        });
                });
            } else {
                this.on(`latest.${column}`, `${tableName}.${column}`);
            }
        });
    })
```

I was not able to re-create your case entirely because I don't have access to your `filterFn`. But without that the sql I get from the above using `console.log(x.toString())` ends up being

```
select sum(`current`) 
from (
    select 
        `study_id`, 
        `site_id`, 
        `status`, 
        max(`day`) as `day` 
    from 
        `candidates` 
    group by `study_id`, 
    `site_id`, 
    `status`) as `latest` 
    inner join `candidates` on `latest`.`day` = `candidates`.`day` 
    and `latest`.`study_id` = `candidates`.`study_id` 
    and (`latest`.`site_id` = `candidates`.`site_id` or 
        (`latest`.`site_id` is null and `candidates`.`site_id` is null)) 
    and `latest`.`status` = `candidates`.`status`
```

Which looks like what you are after (assuming your `filterFn` adds in the required `where` clause)

Comment: Yes the filterFn adds the where clause based on a filter value in the request. Great I'll give to that a shot